# Tax calculation question from Forbes article

Tags: income-tax, 401k, roth-401k

From this article, [When To Use Pre-Tax Vs Roth 401(k) Contributions](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kristinmckenna/2021/12/09/when-to-use-pre-tax-vs-roth-401k-contributions/?sh=66bf50ea53a5), I'm confused on how the 31% difference was calculated from the given example:

For example, if your household taxable income is $500,000, you're in the 35% marginal tax bracket.¹ If you retire in 2022 and have taxable income of $340,000 from pre-tax retirement accounts, you're at the top of the 24% marginal tax bracket for married couples. So the question is: should you pay tax now or later? With only basic math, the tax on ordinary income is 31% more while working vs the year after.

I don't have a strong grasp on taxes, but from using the 2021 and 2022 filling jointly tax tables I calculated:

2021: $95,686 + .35($500,000-$418,850) = $124,088.5

2022: $30,427 + .24($340,000 - $178,150) = $69271

This gives a ~79% difference between the tax amounts. Any explanation on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What you are missing is that the marginal tax rate isn't applied to all of your income. Your income is broken up into the brackets. For example, 10% on the first $9,950, 12% on the next ~ $30k, 22% on the next ~$50k, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe I do account for income being broken into brackets (I've just added all the amounts together for the lower brackets, using this chart [Tax Brackets](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/taxes/federal-income-tax-brackets)). I'm still not sure about the 31% difference though.